# CORS header issue in react Django application

Tags: python, reactjs, django, cors, django-cors-headers

We are using Django with react and in the `settings.py` file we have set the `CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL` to `True`. we have also installed the coresheader app. but when the frontend is going to request for an API from `http://localhost:3000/`
but we still get the CORS policy error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://backend.com/api/v1/Category' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Here is the `settings.py` file configurations:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
...,
    'corsheaders',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    ....,
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',

]
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'frontEnd/build'),
                  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'), ],
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
        #  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'venv/lib/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates')
        ],

        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
            'libraries': {
                'staticfiles': 'django.templatetags.static',
            },

        },
    },
]
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'frontEnd/build/static'), ]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media/'
CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = 'ck/'
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'toolbar': 'full'
    },
}
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
```

And here is how the frontend makes the API call requests using Axios:

```
import axios from 'axios'
import { readCookie } from 'utils/readCookie'
const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
const csrfToken = readCookie('csrftoken')

/** to log in to server using token in all requests */
const token = process.env.REACT_APP_SECRET_KEY
const CancelToken = axios.CancelToken
  const source = CancelToken.source()
export const request = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://backend.com/api/v1',
  headers: {
      Authorization: token ? `Token ${token}` : '',
      'X-CSRFToken': isProduction ? csrfToken : null,
    },
  cancelToken: source.token,
  
})
```

Comment: Allowing arbitrary origins with credentials expose your users to cross-origin attacks. Don't do that. Instead, only allow a select number of Web origins in your CORS configuration.

Comment: Now to solve your configuration issue... `corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware` should be listed first in the `MIDDLEWARE` list. You'll also need to list `Authorization` and `X-CSRFToken` as allowed request headers in your CORS config.